# Pass context through multiple nested inclusion tags in Django

Tags: django, templatetags, inclusion

I'd like to pass the 'context' variable through multiple inclusion tags in Django like so:

base.html:

```
{% load extras %}
{% table_of_contents course %}
```

table-of-contents.html:

```
{% load extras %}

<h1>Table of contents</h1>
{% for section in course.sections %}
    {% display_section section %}
{% endfor %}
```

extras.py:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('table-of-contents.html', takes_context=True)
def table_of_contents(context, course):

    return {
        'course': course,
    }

@register.inclusion_tag('display_section.html', takes_context=True)
def section_expanded(context, section):

    # Identify the user from the context request
    user = context['request'].user

    return {
        'section': section,
        'completed': section.has_been_completed_by(user),
        'outstanding_modules': section.get_outstanding_modules_for(user)
    }
```

However, when I run the code above, I get a key error because the context variable is not passed through to the second inclusion tag:

```
KeyError at /courses/pivottables-video-course/table-of-contents/
'request'
```

How can I ensure that the context variable persists when passed through to multiple nested inclusion tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining new context with `return {'foo': 'bar'}` for your templates – and this new context doesn't contain `request` key. By default `context['request']` is set by `request` context processor (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request).

If you want to pass `context['request']` through multiple tags, you can do this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('table-of-contents.html', takes_context=True)
def table_of_contents(context, course):

    return {
        # ...
        'request': context.get('request'),
        # ...
    }

@register.inclusion_tag('display_section.html', takes_context=True)
def section_expanded(context, section):

    # Identify the user from the context request
    user = context['request'].user

    return {
        # ...
        'request': context.get('request'),
        # ...
    }
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Late to the party, but you save my day! Thanks.